# How can I add extra data to a ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm making a calorie counter. The user can pick from a list of Dishes (easy with a [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield)), but they also need to specify how many servings of each `Dish` they had, where the `serving_size` is a field of my `Dish` model.

Basically, I want it to look like this:

[image: There's a checkbox for each Dish, and underneath each checkbox, there's a number input field for the number of servings you ate.]

The problem is that in order to display the strings "4 oz servings" and "slices", I need access to the `Dish` model when the field is rendered.

What's the best way to do this?

---

I've got 2 rough ideas so far:

1. Create a custom `Widget` that will render as a checkbox AND a number input field. When the data gets deserialized, it becomes something like this:

   ```
   {"dish": <Dish model>, "servings": 2.5}
   ```
2. Just use the regular `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget, but add the `Dish` model itself to the template's context. That way I can do something like this:

   ```
   {% for dish in form.fountain_dishes %}
       {{dish}}
       I ate <input type="number"> {{dish.context.serving_size}}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   However, I'm not sure how to make my `clean` method handle this unexpected data.

Comment: What does the `Dish` model look like? Are there any other models involved in the form?

Comment: Dishes have a `name`, a `serving_size`, and a number of `calories`. This form is supposed to create a Meal object, which has a ManyToMany field containing all the Dishes the user ate, and the total number of calories for that meal.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm in sore need of a widget that allows me to fill in extra data for every item selected in a m2m relationship.

Comment: @Ithilion I broke down and implemented it in javascript.

Here's my template (notice line 6): https://gitlab.com/mac-chaffee/ncsu-menu-notifier/blob/master/calories/templates/calorie_form.html

And here's my javascript: https://gitlab.com/mac-chaffee/ncsu-menu-notifier/blob/master/calories/static/calorie_form.js